# How to stop a sub which calls upon multiple subs

Tags: vba, excel

I have been creating a tool which extracts data from other Excel files and does various types of analysis. Because of these numerous different analyses, I have had to create multiple subs which are then all called upon in a "master" sub, which is activated when the user presses a button.

The issue I'm having is with error handling to stop the macro when there's an issue or when the user is trying to stop the code themselves - e.g. a pop-up box appears with a "continue or stop" type scenario. However, I can't work out how to make the macros stop! Using `Exit Sub` doesn't work because the master sub will then just jump to the next sub in the queue.

See example below - the user presses the button to activate master_sub. If within the sub1 stage the user selects "No" or "Cancel" in a MsgBox, sub1 will end (if using `Exit Sub`) but master_sub will then just go on to sub2 and sub3. How do I make master_sub stop based upon an input/action within sub1?

```
Sub sub1()
    Dim MyMsg as Variant
    MyMsg = msgbox("Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo)
    If MyMsg = 7 then 'If user clicks "No"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        'Do stuff
    End if
End Sub

Sub sub2()
    'More stuff
End Sub

Sub sub3()
    'Other stuff
End Sub

master_sub()
    call sub1
    call sub2
    call sub3
End Sub
```

Comment: if you are writing a macro, you arent using VB.NET

Comment: Yeah, not sure where the vb.net tag came from. Now modified.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Exit Sub Throw a custom exception and catch it in your master_sub.

Something like

```
Sub sub1()
    Dim MyMsg as Variant
    MyMsg = msgbox("Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo)
    If MyMsg = 7 then 'If user clicks "No"
       Throw new MyException
    Else
        'Do stuff
    End if
End Sub

master_sub()
 Try
    call sub1
    call sub2
    call sub3
 Catch ex as MyException
'Do something if you want
 End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Note: This answer was posted while the question had a [vb.net] tag.  The answer is not applicable in [vba].

Answer (score 0):

The "how does master_sub" detect when one of the child methods has been cancelled can be solved like this:

```
Sub master_sub()
    Dim result As Boolean

    result = Sub1()
    If (result = False) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    result = Sub2()
    If (result = False) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    result = Sub3()
    If (result = False) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub

Function Sub1() As Boolean
    Return True
End Function

Function Sub2() As Boolean
    Return False
End Function

Function Sub3() As Boolean
    Return True
End Function
```

I've kept it very simple, but basically by changing from a [`Sub`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz1z94ha.aspx) to a [`Function`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sect4ck6.aspx) you can have each method return a value and decide in your main routine (`master_sub`) what to do depending on the value returned.